# server trace naming convention

Tags: oracle-12c, trace, sqlnet

I wanted to extract some information from the server trace file that is generated after I send a connect statement to the database. I wanted to know the naming convention for the server trace file. I could figure out that the name is in the below format:

`<ORACLE_SID>_ORA_<4_digit_ID>`.trc

I wanted to know what is the 4_digit_id that is appended at the end of the trace. As per my research it seems to the process id of the oracle server. I queried the v$process for the pid column, however it seems to be returning multiple values and that too are not in 4 digit. It would be really appreciated if an expert can comment on this.

Is there a way to identify the spid of a failed login attempt? For instance I would like to know the spid for the process when I issue the below command:

`sqlplus non_existent_user/random_password`

BTW, the server trace is enabled through sqlnet.ora where trace_level_server=16 is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PID` is the internal (to the database) ID of database processes.

The `SPID` column contains the OS process ID, that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @BalazsPapp for the response. Yes you are correct. It is the SPID column indeed.
Is there a way to identify the spid of a failed login attempt? For instance I would like to know the spid for the process when I issue the below command:
sqlplus non_existent_user/random_password

Comment: @Shekhar Kanodia That is a different question. You can use the `OS_PROCESS` column from `DBA_AUDIT_SESSION` or `UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL` views depending in which kind of auditing you have enabled.